# How do I remove the | special character in a CHAR dataset using proc sql?

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I am trying to remove the charater | using proc sql. The position of | is not fixed and varies in the data, hence I do not want to use the substr  function

Example 1- 1234|5678|9|101
Example 2 - 12345|6789|1|011

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRANSLATE()` function

```
UPDATE tab
   SET TRANSLATE(Col, '', '|')
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you could use REPLACE, something like

```
SELECT REPLACE('1234|5678|9|101 Example 2 - 12345|6789|1|011','|','') Changed
     FROM DUAL;
```